# Intellij - Python interpretor

Tags: python, maven, intellij-idea

I have an MVN project and would like to add a Python program in the project. The IDE I am using in Intellij.

1. I have added the MVN pom file as below:

   org.codehaus.mojo
   versions-maven-plugin
   2.1



   python
   src/main/resources/pythonlib 

   PYTHONPATH
2. Added the Python plugin
3. While trying to run from the editor it is asking for Python interpreter:

Which has 2 radio buttons:

- Use SDK of the module
- Use specified interpreter.

In both the list does not have any Python interpreter. How to have the list display a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Added the interpreter at module level in project settings an it worked fine for me. 
Project Settings -> Modules -> Click + an added the python home directory.